# Move files with PowerShell to a remote location up a level if a file doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, recursive-datastructures

I would like to recursively search a directory and move the contents of a folder if a file doesn't exist to a remote server and remove a folder level.

E.g., only copy the contents of folder 2 because file.txt doesn't exist.

**SOURCE SERVER**

```
C:\folder\folder1\foldera - test.txt file.txt

C:\folder\folder2\foldera - test.txt
```

*would become*

**DESTINATION SERVER**

```
C:\folder\folder2\ - test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have misunderstood your question from the beginning. I have just realized that your conditions to copy a file over is *only if they exists in both folders*.

We can use the [Compare-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx) cmdlet to achieve that. What the code below does is compare the listings of the 2 folders, check for equivalents based on file/dir names and copies them to the destination folder.

```
$target_directory = Get-Item -Path '\\dest-server\c$\folder\folder2'

$set1 = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\test1' -Recurse
$set2 = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\test2' -Recurse

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $set1 -DifferenceObject $set2 -Property Name -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru | ForEach-Object { 

    # Copy files but will not overwrite files, use -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to suppress errors. 
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $target_directory.FullName -ErrorAction Continue

}
```

Comment: Hi foldera will always be the same name but folder1/2 will always be named differently. I need to check for the existence of the file first and foremost. Many thanks for all the replies :)

Comment: Robocopy does a comparison of the destination file. If its the same it will not execute the copy. Do you want it to behave differently?

Comment: I want it to check in the foldera for the existence of that specific file. Only if it isn't there will it copy everything on folder up to a remote location

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best code ever, but it should do the job with minor adjustments:

```
$Tester = "C:\Dell\Drivers\Sata\Test"

$Folders = [array]$Tester.split("\")
Write-Host $Folders
$Folders |`
ForEach {
    $CureToken = "$_\"
    if(Test-Path -Path "$Good$CureToken")
        {
        $Good = "$Good$CureToken"
        Write-Host $Good
        }
    }
    Write-Host "This Path Is Good: $Good"
```

It returns the good path (Which is two directories higher than the original string. It looks like:

```
C:\Dell\Drivers\
This Path Is Good: C:\Dell\Drivers\
```

You can use this to see how it works, and with minor edits update it for UNC paths.

You can also use

```
Copy-Item -Path $MyFileToCopy -Destination $Good
```

For the actual copy.